# How can I make a function that prints a histogram based on the indexes of a list (more detalis inside)?

Tags: python

So, I found this exercise.

Define a procedure histogram() that takes a list of integers and prints a histogram to the screen. For example, histogram([2, 1, 3]) should print the following:

XX

X

XXX

But I just can't do it. I am trying to write an algorithm that reads lists independent of their lengths. (Meaning you could input a list with 1, 2, or whatever number of objects you wanted)

Comment: Put some code which is your starting point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple histogram program that take list of input from the user and print the histogram output.

```
def histogram(list):
        for x in range(0,len(list)):
                print('X' * list[x])
        return
li=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
histogram(li)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def histogram( items ):
    for n in items:
        output = ''
        times = n
        while( times > 0 ):
          output += '*'
          times = times - 1
        print(output)

histogram([2, 3, 6, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation from R Schultz exercise, Thanks , you showed me the way....

```
def histogram():
   a = raw_input("Pleas give a number: ").split()
   for i in range(len(a)):
      print int(a[i]) * "X"

histogram()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple histogram program that take list of input from the user and print the histogram output.

```
def histogram(list):
        for x in range(0,len(list)):
                print('X' * list[x])
        return
li=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
histogram(li)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def list(n):
    for i in n:
        print('X '*i)

list([2,1,3])
```